# unescape alternative in node.js

Tags: node.js, escaping, deprecated

I'm using the deprecated `unescape` function in one of my program.

The protocol I'm working with sends `escape`d binary strings via the query string. So on their side they are doing something along the lines of (0-9, a-z, A-Z, '.', '-', '_' and '~' are encoded using the "%nn" format):

```
var source = "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a";
var encoded = escape(source);
// escaped is now "%124Vx%9A%BC%DE%F1%23Eg%89%AB%CD%EF%124Vx%9A"
```

So I'm receiving this string on my end and I have to decode it. `decodeURIComponent` is not working in this case so I rely on `unescape`:

```
var received = "%124Vx%9A%BC%DE%F1%23Eg%89%AB%CD%EF%124Vx%9A";
var binaryString = unescape(received);
```

Since `unescape` is deprecated, any pointers on how should I decode these binary strings?

Note: `querystring.unescape` doesn't work either...

Answer (score 2):

Having a similar issue here, after doing some research I found this which can still be of use to someone.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/unescape

Answer (score -4):

The `unescape()` function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use `decodeURI()` or `decodeURIComponent()` instead.

The `unescape()` function decodes an encoded string.